# Third party extension issue with custom theme

Tags: third-party-module, magento2.4.1, magento-2-commerce, issue

I have created a custom theme which i inherit from the blank theme, if i applied  third party extension its not applied, i am tried with couple of extensions same issue, what are all the necessary steps to follow for install a third party extension in **custom theme**

Answer (score 1):

There is no different way to install extension for custom theme or for default theme.

1. First upload your extension in app/code/ folder
2. Run below commands in CLI to install your extension

   bin/magento setup:upgrade

   bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

   bin/magento cache:flush

   chmod -Rf 0777 var/ generated/ pub/
3. After that please check in config.php file(app/etc/) to check that your extension is installed or not.
   You can check it with your PackageName_Module

Please follow above steps and let me know if you have any query.

Comment: Is answer working for you? Please let me know if you face any issue

Comment: @zus Have you tried?